# Putting certain lines of a textfile into an editable listbox

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

So I want to put certain lines into a text box, say I use the "Search Function" to search transaction ID, it would look through the transactions.txt file and find the transaction ID and Read the 6 lines under it which show the transactions Details, once found this would then go to a the listbox which then you could edit the transaction.

I was wondering would you use loops and arrays to do this, and could someone show me how, Thank you!

Heres my current code:

```
  //Creates a textfile with details of the transaction
    public void CreateFile()
{
     StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.AppendText("Transactions.txt");
        outputFile.WriteLine("Investor :" +" " + InvestorNameLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Initial Amount" + " " +AmountLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Date Invested" +" " +DateLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Period Chosen" + " "+DaysInvestedLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Rate Chosen" + " " + RateLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Total Interest" + " " +InterestAmountLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Transaction Number :" + " " + TransactionIDLabel.Text);
        outputFile.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Transaction file for Transaction: " + TransactionIDLabel.Text + " " +"Was Created", "Transaction File");
       }

       //puts all transactions in listbox
       //needs to be able to find certain transactions

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("transactions.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
string ID = "23";
bool idFound=false;
int count = 0;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("transactions.txt"))
{
    if (idFound  && count < 6)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(line);
        count++;
    }
    if(line.Contains(ID))//if you wantto match exactly use if(line.Equals(ID))
    {
        idFound = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: its working thank you,  but the lines are going horizontal and not vertically. How would I fix that.
Thanks again! :)

Comment: @user2884461: sorry i didn't get you. `but the lines are going horizontal and not vertically` could be please explain it?

Comment: Lines retrieved are Horizontal, Eg. Name : Mr Hank, Address : 2412, Street :FineAve instead of vertical such as this. Name : Mr Hank \n Address : 2412 Street : FineAve. Edit : Sorry comments wont let me format vertically.

Comment: @user2884461: if you are using `listBox` you don't get the items in one row, could you please edit your post with latest code and if possible also add snapshot of listbox.